# Ubuntu-Software is too buggy in Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: 18.10, gnome-software

Sometimes I can't go back to the main page, sometimes I can't search, I always need to `pkill gnome-softwares`, is there going to be a bug fix?

Comment: Is there a bug report on launchpad for the issue?   If there isn't, then the developers can't know about the issue and no it won't be fixed.  This site is for users, so developers are extremely unlikely to see what's here unless one of us users goes to launchpad & files a bug-report (and it should be done on a machine having the issue, as `ubuntu-bug` can gain information useful to help finding the cause & thus fixing it..).  Did you report it?

Comment: @guiverc Done! https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1801585